# Http 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: jsp, arguments, internal-server-error, get-request

http://localhost:8080/file.jsp?arg1=&arg2=11

runs successfully

http://localhost:8080/file.jsp?arg1=&arg2=

(empty value for argument 'arg2')

shows 500 Internal Server Error

The value of 'arg2' is used by an '`int`' variable in '`jsp`' using `Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("arg2")`

How to fix it?

Comment: Which app server you are using. It is the server/application issue. Check if your application is handling null values, or else check with the server support.

Comment: "HTTP 500 internal server error" is an overly generic message that the server has a problem processing the request. This is in turn usually caused by a bug in the server side code. This information is visible in the server logs, usually in flavor of an exception and a stacktrace. You, as a developer, should pay attention to this exception. Just telling "I got a 500 error" is absolutely not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are trying to parse "" with `Integer.parseInt`

Check [Integer parseInt() API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

When you do not pass any values Like below

```
http://localhost:8080/file.jsp?arg1=&arg2=
```

Empty string will be passed in http request parameters.

So, better put empty check when parsing integer from string.

```
int arg2 = !"".equals(request.getParameter("arg2")) ? 
                Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("arg2")): 0;
```

Comment: This doesn't cover string values containing non-digits. E.g. `arg2=foo`.

Comment: @BalusC: I agree but there is a different validation required using regx or pattern matcher in java +5.

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to check the query parameters against what is needed.
In this case you can use [org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html) library to check if the entered value is a number or not and use default value in case it is not a number.

```
int arg2 = NumberUtils.isNumber(request.getParameter("arg2")) ? Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("arg2")) : 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Internet Explorer, go to Tools - Internet Options - Advanced - under Browsing untick "Show Friendly HTTP Error Messages". This will allow you to get a better description of what the error is.

To help you with your code itself, you will need to post it.

Comment: It is a sever issue. Browser has nothing to do with this.